# Cannot make Slider to be responsive

Tags: css, image, position, responsive

[image: This is how i want to look]I've run into a problem.I'm trying to build a full-screen image slider with responsive images.I tried all combination:Add style height:100%,width :100% ,height:auto,width:auto  in HTML,in CSS but nothing seems to work.I will show you the code maybe i've done something wrong.
I cannot add code snippet because are doesn't display images and it's a lot of code and classes.This problem is driven me crazy,i`m looking for a fix for 4 hours.
[image: This is how my images looks]

HTML

```
<div id="showcase">
    <div id="arrow-left" class="arrow"></div>
    <div id="slider">
      <div class="slide slide1"></div>
      <div class="slide slide2 "></div>
      <div class="slide  slide3"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="arrow-right" class="arrow"></div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#showcase,
#slider,
.slide-content {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#showcase {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide1 {
  background: url(/Core/img/lazar1.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.slide2 {
  background: url(/Core/img/lazar2.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.slide3 {
  background: url(/Core/img/lazar3.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.arrow {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  border-style: solid;
}

#arrow-left {
  border-width: 30px 40px 30px 0;
  border-color: transparent blue transparent transparent;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#arrow-right {
  border-width: 30px 0 30px 40px;
  border-color: transparent blue transparent blue;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `100vw` and `100vh` for your width and height, respectively?

Comment: Yes,doesn`t working.

Comment: Sorry, I'd like to better understand what is happening on your page that is not working, can you be a bit more specific about the problem? Are the images not appearing full screen? Are they coming up distorted?

Comment: No, they appear but the size of images are not changing when the page is smaller.I tried all the methods to make them responsive, but nothing seems to work.I want to copy the website of LazarAngelov.com.Please have a look there

Comment: Ok. I copied your code into my browser and used some test images (because I cannot access yours). The only thing I changed is I set the units of your .`slide` class to   `vw` and `vh` for the width and height, and the images (for me) come up full screen and scale appropriately when I resize the window. I know you said you've tried this before, but in all the combinations, you might have missed it. Can you try this and let me know if it works?

Comment: I edited the post  and copied some images,please have a look.

Comment: Did my last suggestion not work?

Comment: Sorry, just saw that. There must be something extra in your code (either HTML or CSS), that is not in mine that is preventing this. I'll look more closely at your example. Still, i'm puzzled why it works for me and not you.

Comment: Ok, sorry for all the questions (even if some are dumb), i'm just trying to consider all possibilities. Firstly, did you remember to add a `<meta>` viewport tag? Secondly, what size (in px) are the images you're using? And lastly, what happens if you use `vw` for the height as well as the width?

Comment: there is nothing in my code ,i checked with code pen,and with code pen gives me same thing

Comment: https://codepen.io/ConsttantinAk98/pen/MRMgap

Comment: when i resize from corner it`s works but when you make the page smaller horizontally doesn`t work.Also thank you very much for your effort

Comment: No problem. I think I see what's happening - when the page shrinks width-wise, the image begins to shrink. Once the image shrinks to the point it's at it's native height, it stops shrinking and the width starts getting overridden. The question is why. I'll play with the codepen for a few and see if I can come up with anything.

Comment: Got it. I really should have thought of this sooner. The site you're using as an example uses media queries to reduce the div height of `.slide`  at certain breakpoints. Check out this fiddle --- https://jsfiddle.net/26fjemko/3/

Comment: Lol... I was thinking that`s a property that I`m missing. Thank you a lot, If you can post the answer I will give you that green check if you need. God Bless you!

Comment: Sounds like a deal. Give me a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix a problem like this, for responsive design, use media queries. The page being referenced uses media queries at certain width breakpoints to reduce the height of the div containing the images so as to allow the screen to shrink width-wise while still displaying the image with an intact aspect ratio (as they are rather wide images). An example in code would look like this:

```
//HTML
<div id="showcase">
    <div id="arrow-left" class="arrow"></div>
    <div id="slider">
      <div class="slide slide1"></div>
      <div class="slide slide2 "></div>
      <div class="slide  slide3"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="arrow-right" class="arrow"></div>
  </div>

//CSS
#showcase,#slider{
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
}
.slide{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh
}
.slide1{
  background:url(http://www.lazarangelov.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/lazar3-1920.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .slide{
    height: 80vh;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .slide{
    height: 70vh;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .slide{
    height: 60vh;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .slide{
    height: 50vh;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .slide{
    height: 40vh;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .slide{
    height: 30vh;
  }
}
```

Please be aware that these are not spectacular examples of media queries, they are simply being used to demonstrate the mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Add below codes to "slide" class:

```
background-size: contain !important;
```

Comment: It Works, Thank you, very simple solution.

Comment: This technique is good for those who want the image to be in the center.